# laravel query builder : I have mysql query

Tags: laravel

I have the following MySQL query that I want to convert to a Laravel 5.8 query builder. How could I do this?

```
SELECT 
    u.id, 
    u.username,
    (select count(*)  as invalid_count from invalid_template_messaging where user_id = u.id) as t1,
     (select count(*)  as valid_count from template_messagings where user_id = u.id) as t2 FROM  
    users as u GROUP BY 
    u.id
```

Comment: When attempting to write the query builder statement yourself, where did you get stuck?

Comment: You can use laravel  eloquent relationships like https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: I am new in laravel

Answer (score 0):

> You can write this query like that

```
DB::select(`u.id`,`u.username`)
        ->selectSub(`select count as invalid_count from invalid_template_messaging where user_id = u.id`, `t1`)
        ->selectSub(`select count as valid_count from template_messagings where user_id = u.id`, `t2`)
        ->from(`users as u`)
        ->groupBy(`u.id`)
        ->get();
```